# How to enable Inkscape experimental LPE (Powerstroke) in Ubuntu

Tags: inkscape

I stumbled upon the Powerstroke experimental LPE for Inkscape and really want to try it out, but I cannot find the means to do it. [This](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/PowerStroke) article states:

```
To test the LPE, Inkscape must be built with experimental LPE's enabled.
You have to build Inkscape with

 #define LPE_ENABLE_TEST_EFFECTS

otherwise the LPE won't show in the LPE dialog.
(uncommenting line 9 in src/live_effects/effect.cpp will do the trick)
```

However, I cannot find the effect.cpp file, nor any other means to enable experimental LPEs. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I was able to install the developer version of Inkscape which contains the latest experimentals. I just followed the description here: https://launchpad.net/~inkscape.dev/+archive/trunk